# Why opened page with AdminLTE looks broken?

Tags: css, laravel, vue.js

I make site In laravel 9 with Inertiajs/vuejs 3 based on https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE 3 (dark mode).
I removed all jquery and use vuejs only. it works ok for for, but when I open site
is looks broken, like not all styles were loaded,

Please try enter to login into adminarea by url :

https://bi-currencies.my-demo-apps.tk/admin/currencies

credentials are in Login form

and pages looks like : https://prnt.sc/TCjBh0SefUMO 4

But if to refresh page with “CTRL+R” pages looks ok, in dark mode.

Any ideas why so and how that can be fixed?

**More Details :**
Adminare is based on https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE  template(with "bootstrap": "^4.6.0").
Frontend is based on custom https://technext.github.io/space/v1.0.0/  template (with Bootstrap v5.0.1 )

I have the same design issue when I switch from admin area
frontend page https://bi-currencies.my-demo-apps.tk/home

I see this problem of other browsers of my Kubuntu 20 too.

Maybe problem is that that I use too different templates, but actually I use different layouts, so in

```
app/Http/Middleware/HandleInertiaRequests.php :

    public function rootView(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->segment(1) == 'user') {
            return 'layouts/user';
        }
        if ($request->segment(1) == 'admin') {
            return 'layouts/adminlte'; // TODO
        }

        return 'layouts/frontend'; // Current request is front-end
    }
```

This project has no Redis or other chache tools installed. Sure I cleared all cache opening the site. Any other ideas?
Frontend template resources/views/layouts/frontend.blade.php  :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title inertia id="app_title">{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/frontend_favicon.ico">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Yantramanav:wght@300;400;500;700;900&amp;display=swap"
          rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->


    @routes

    <!-- Scripts -->

    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/theme.css">

    <script src="/vendors/@popperjs/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/vendors/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/vendors/is/is.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=window.scroll"></script>
    <script src="/vendors/fontawesome/all.min.js"></script>

    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

</head>
<body class="bg-light sidebar-mini layout-fixed layout-footer-fixed">
@inertia
</body>
</html>
```

and admin template resources/views/layouts/adminlte.blade.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title inertia id="app_title">{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

        <!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&display=fallback">

        <!-- Styles -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/OverlayScrollbars.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/fontawesome_all.min.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/adminlte.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/admin_custom.css">

        @routes

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

        <script src="/js/Chart.bundle.js"></script>

        <script src="/js/OverlayScrollbars.min.js"></script>

        <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body class="bg-light sidebar-mini layout-fixed layout-footer-fixed">
        @inertia
    </body>
</html>
```

1 common resources/js/app.js :

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Toast = Swal.mixin({
    toast: true,
    position: 'top-end',
    showConfirmButton: false,
    timer: 3000,
    timerProgressBar: false,
    didOpen: (toast) => {
        toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer)
        toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer)
    }
})

require('@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.min.js');

// Import modules...
import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp, Link } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress';

import mitt from 'mitt';
window.emitter = mitt();


const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'Laravel';

import Multiselect from '@vueform/multiselect'

import VueUploadComponent from 'vue-upload-component'
import Paginate from "vuejs-paginate-next";


const app =  createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}.vue`),
    setup({ el, app, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .component('inertia-link', Link)
            .component('Paginate', Paginate)
            .component('file-upload', VueUploadComponent)

            .mixin({ methods: { route } })
            .component('multiselect', Multiselect)
            .mount(el);
    },
});

InertiaProgress.init({ color: '#4B5563' });
```

also in admin/settings page I added “Clear Cache” button, clicking on it next commands are run :

```
\Artisan::call('config:cache');
\Artisan::call('route:cache');
\Artisan::call('cache:clear');
\Artisan::call('route:cache');
\Artisan::call('route:clear');
\Artisan::call('view:clear');
\Artisan::call('clear-compiled');
```

but clearing cache did not help with this problem.
Can it be that reason of this problem that I have 1 common resources/js/app.js  both for admin area and frontend part?

---

Thanks!

Comment: 1) I tried one of prior versions before I added frontend part : it has the same issue with first time page opened and broken design.
So I suppose that is some different problem, but not conflict with custom frontend design.

2) I uploaded the project at public https://github.com/sergeynilov/BiCurrencies repository.
Could you please install it and take a look ?
Just common laravel app with common install steps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I was faced same problem with inertia and that works for me. Usually that happened when you used `multiple-layouts`, as well as those layout have different `style-scripts`.

###### Reason (problem):

As you have used one layout for `frontend-pages (public pages)` and other one for `admin-pages`.

So when user visited `front-pages`, all style scripts of `frontend-layout` loaded and it's work fine and looks good.

But, when user switched to `admin-layout` that's layout `style-scripts` not loaded. So, On `hard-refresh (Crtl+R)` that URL the appropriate layout style-scripts got loaded.

I read many article to switch layouts on run-time every article gives same solutions as you did in `HandleInertiaRequests.php`.

###### Solution:

Then I come to a point where I need to switch layout on clicking some `link` I did `hard-loading` as shown in below snippet ***instead*** of redirection by `inertia-link`:

```
<a :href="route('home')">
   Home                           
</a>
```

By this way appropriate layout `style-script` got loaded.

---

###### My Assumption:

Moreover, I've seen your site-source-code (Ctrl+U) as shown in screenshot. You haven't loaded `style-scripts` by Laravel `asset()` helper method.

[image: scripts-complete-url-not-rendered]

I suggest to try once by loading `scripts & style link` in blade file by Laravel standard approach ***(using `asset()` method)*** that might be a problem.

- ***Attach CSS sheet***

```
  <link href="{{ asset('frontend/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

- ***Attach JavaScript/jQuery scripts***

```
<script src="{{ asset('frontend/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js') }}"></script>
```

After using `asset()` method, your links in site-source-code (Ctrl+U)
looks something like that:

[image: load style/scripts using asset() method in laravel]

###### Note:

make sure you must set appropriate `APP_URL` in `.env` file.

Comment: Thanks! That seems good assumption when switching from one layout to another. But I have the same issue when opening the page for the first time, say  wuth url in new browser. Please take a look at this

Comment: @mstdmstd I've updated my above answer please read **my assumption** section, that might help you